# II6 Basic Authentication and RouteTable.Routes

Tags: asp.net, routes, iis-6, url-routing

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms site that is running on a IIS6/Server 2003 instance. The site itself does not permit anonymous access and uses IIS basic authentication before the user can get to the Forms authentication screen. However, there are two site nodes below the site level, that are virtual directories which DO permit anonymous access (for requesting static images by other machines).

A new request required me to route those requests to a different page and examine the URL being requested and perform different tasks. I’m using a MapPageRoute method in the Global.asax file and the route clears through Forms authentication with a web.config setting `<allow users="*" />`. Obviously, that works great locally, but when deployed to the IIS6 machine basic authentication kicks in before the request gets routed.

Is there a good way to "fake" or create a virtual directory node in IIS6 and grant it anonymous access so that the routed url request can execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not work for everyone, but since in my case HTTP Authentication was primarily instituted just to prevent people from multiple attempts at the login page, I actually removed Basic Authentication from the site and all virtual directory nodes.

Then I added it just to the ~/[loginpage] that was being used. Since forms authentication was in use all unauthenticated users are re-directed to the login page and then get the basic authentication. Since the routed page request needed to be public I just added it as an exception to the Web.config. The routed values have to meet a very strict criteria to even be executed by the page logic and everything else is returned as a 404 by the handler.

Obviously this means that the asp.net dll is executing before IIS basic security when requests are redirected to the login page, but in this case I think it is fine.